# SDL Web 8.5 - How to find a User created date and privilege modified date

Tags: core-service, gui-extensions, event-system, web8.5, api

I have business requirement to create a Tridion Active User List report with name, privilege, description, `created date and privilege modified date`.

I checked the `TRUSTEES` table and not find the user created date and privilege modified date` fields.

```
SELECT ID,
  NAME,
  ENABLED,
  IS_PREDEFINED,
  ITEM_TYPE,
  PRIVILEGE,
  IS_DEFAULT_GROUP,
  DELETED,
  DESCRIPTION,
  LANGUAGE_ID,
  LOCALE_ID
FROM TCMDBUSER.TRUSTEES
```

**How to find a User created date and privilege modified date.**

```
Any Tridion API support for user created date and privilege modified dates.
```

**Looking for valuable solutions and Ideas.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Trustee database does not provide time stamp data for the creation or modification of the trustee data.

So you will need to add some Tridion Event code to capture these events and maintain your own tracking database.

See [Tridion Event Handlers](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-AB4FBF5F-7C3B-4804-9E7F-FBBF5514A596)